# Change mysql data directory using java

Tags: java, mysql

Is it possible to change the data directory of MySQL using java?

regards
Shihab

Comment: This isn't something that is usually needed as part of a well architected system. Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would like to change the data directory of the my sql from my java program. Like some times, mysql is installed in a C drive and, it may be full due to other programs installation. At that time, I want to change the data directory of the mysql. I can do it from admin module of the mysql. But I want to do from java. Both in windows and linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC URL is used to connect to an existing database or at least to a running mysql TCP server in that case there 's no common sense to change the place where the daemon finds data ...
So I would be tempted to say no... I would not be the case with some embedded databases like Derby or H2 but those are well suited for totally different use cases...
For your information this is the MySQL config page : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

HTH
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

maybe possible. :)
You should use java to modify the my.cnf. and then copy the all data. and then restart mysql using the `Runtime`class. like use the shell script. And that will be ok.